# Repeatedly change background colour of picture onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, css, nested

I have a picture and wish its background to change and repeatedly take random colours sequencially from all over the spectrum till the user's mouse exits the picture. I guess the solution should use setInterval ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)) and the following shall help:

```
var red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
var green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
var blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
var bg = "background-color: rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ");";
x.style = bg;
```

[Here is a fiddle trying to implement what I have in mind](https://jsfiddle.net/kostass/zvebco3r/): The first smiley should change colour onMouseOver and return to normal onMouseOut.

Here is what I have in mind: I want to implement what [FontAwesome.com do on their logo at their footer](https://fontawesome.com/): it changes colours onmouseover and stops otherwise. But that's not a picture, it's a font(?). Instead, I have a logo that I made transparent, and I want to change the background dynamically so that it replicates the nice trick of Fontawesome. Any ideas?

*** Updated ***

I am posting a detailed solution to my question below based on the answers of the community. Looks like I followed Leo's way but Rakibul's solution worked well too.

Comment: You can use css3 animation with keyframes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843880/css3-button-background-color-infinite-transition

Comment: Thank you! I do know how to change the background of a picture to A colour ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/kostass/wujmkco9/)). Instead, I am asking to repeatedly apply a color generating function onMouseOver that will make the background of the picture take _multiple colours_, and then stop it onMouseOut. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, you can use the `animation-play-state: pause` on `hover`

Comment: Thank you @LeoCaseiro, [yes that is towards the right direction](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-play-state_hover). Can you reply with a complete example code applied to the parameters of my problem posted? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `setInterval()` with your required time interval (In the example below 500 is set) for the color to be changed randomly on definite interval. And `onmouseover` is used to simply detect the hover on the image and then it sets the color randomly. Finally, when `onmouseout` is detected, the color changes to no-color.

```js
var randomColor = function() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  return "#" + r + g + b;
};

var colorChange;

document.getElementById("myImage").onmouseover = function() {
  colorChange = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("myImage").style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  }, 500);
};

document.getElementById("myImage").onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "";
  clearInterval(colorChange);
};
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley">
```

Comment: This is great Rakibul! I am accepting it but I liked a lot the answer of Leo as well. I may modify your code a bit so that the transition of the colors is linear/smooth (as this will go to a logo), and post another reply later in case a future user finds this question.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved what I want.

I wanted my logo to change colours "nicely" when a user's mouse hovers over it (like magic and similar to [FontAwesome's logo at their footer](https://fontawesome.com)).

```css
.OAlogo {
  background-color: transparent;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.OAlogo:hover {
  animation: colorReplace 10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes colorReplace {
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(44, 132, 231);
  }
  10% {
    background-color: rgb(61, 192, 90);
  }
  20% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 211, 59);
  }
  30% {
    background-color: rgb(253, 136, 24);
  }
  40% {
    background-color: rgb(243, 129, 174);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(34, 138, 230);
  }
  60% {
    background-color: rgb(62, 192, 89);
  }
  70% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 211, 59);
  }
  80% {
    background-color: rgb(71, 193, 86);
  }
  90% {
    background-color: rgb(253, 126, 20);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(233, 109, 132);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="OAlogo" src="http://www.stouras.com/OperationsAcademia.github.io/images/OA-logo-solo.png" style="background: black;" width="100">
```

Comment: For this result, one needs to make his/her logo transparent, then plot it on a black background (in my case). And when the user hovers over, the colourful animation starts playing.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS animation to change colors and use the `animation-play-state: pause` on hover.

```css
 .button {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: colorReplace 5s infinite;
  }

  .button:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }


@keyframes colorReplace
{
  0%   {background-color:red;}
  30%  {background-color:green;}
  60%  {background-color:blue;}
  100%   {background-color:red;}
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="button" />
```

Comment: Leo rushed a bit, his idea above is working. Will post a _complete_ answer that fully applies to answers what I am asking once done.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `setInterval` function to run your code over and over. You also had some minor errors in your code which I have fixed. See your updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zvebco3r/3/

You can change the interval time (currently 25ms) to your desired length.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
```

**JS:**

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');

img.onmouseover = function() {
    changeIt = setInterval(function(){
       var red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
       var green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
       var blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
       img.style.backgroundColor="rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")";
    },25);
}

img.onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
    clearInterval(changeIt);
}
```